# How to read data from a postgresql database in asp.net web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, postgresql-10

I'm developing a web API with asp.net core and i want to retrieve data from my postgresql database. When there's no data, it displays an empty array but when i add data to the database, it returns an error.

This is for asp.net core 2.2 and PostgreSQL version 10. I set up the database with models using code first and entity framework. I created the controllers using entity framework as well with the models and database context. I tried to make changes to the code in the controllers but nothing has worked.

My client model

```
public class Client
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

My database context

```
public BillingDb(DbContextOptions<BillingDb> options)
    : base(options)
{

}

public virtual DbSet<Account> Account { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Charge> Charge { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }
```

//some code left out

My Clients Controller

```
// GET: api/Clients

[HttpGet]

public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Client>>> GetClient()
{
    return await _context.Client.ToListAsync();
}
```

Expected results for: https://localhost:44399/api/clients

```
[ 
  { "id": 1, 
    "FirstName": "Martha", 
    "LastName": "Lungu", 
  } 
]
```

Error am getting

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. 
InvalidCastException: Can't cast database type text[] to String 
Npgsql.NpgsqlDefaultDataReader.GetFieldValue(int column) in 
NpgsqlDefaultDataReader.cs, line 104

BillingService.Controllers.ClientsController.GetClient() in 
ClientsController.cs + return await _context.Client.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It works well when I use your code.As the error says that,what and where is the `type text[]` in your situation?

Comment: text[] is the data type saved in the postgresql database for some reason.

Comment: Since your model properies are string type, maybe you need to match it with the database data type

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data as a Json

```
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Client>>> GetClient()
  {
     var myData=await _context.Client.ToListAsync();
     return Json(myData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```